# Python check if array row or column exist and extend array size if needed

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose that I have an array of (2,2) dimension:
`matrix = np.zeros([2, 2])`
I'd like to add the value 1 at the following position (3, 1).
Of course the matrix is too small.
How can I check if the index of the row and the column exist in this array and extend it automatically if it does not exist and this for any new position. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This simple code can detect if the row and column exists:

If it exists : Change the value

If it doesn't :

1. Create the missing lines with only zeros
2. Update the dimensions of matrix m
3. Create the missing columns with only zeros
4. Replace the value in the correct index

   ```
   def add_value(matrix, value, row, column):
       nbcol = matrix.ndim-1
       nbrow = len(matrix)-1
       if nbcol >= column and nbrow >= row:
           matrix[row,column] = value
       return matrix
   else:
       m = matrix
       for i in range(nbrow,row):
           m = np.append(m, np.zeros([1,nbcol+1]), axis=0)
           nbrow = len(m)-1
           nbcol = m.ndim-1
       for i in range(nbcol,column):
           m = np.append(m, np.zeros([nbrow+1,1]), axis=1)
       m[row,column] = value
       return m

   if __name__  == "__main__":
       m1 = np.zeros([2, 2])
       print(m1)
       m1 = add_value(m1, 6, 2, 2)
       print(m1)
   ```

Don't forget that the index starts at 0! So

```
m[0,0]
```

gives the value of the first row and first column!

Comment: It does work perfectly. I just have an additional question. If I have value with position (-1, 2) for exemple. The row index is -1 in this case. Is it possible to extend it in the other direction ?

Comment: It has also an issue: for `m [[ 1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  2. -2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]. `Adding value 2 at (2,9) gives error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 30 and the array at index 1 has size 2 (for the line of code: m = np.append(m, np.zeros([1,nbcol+1]), axis=0)

Comment: FYI, for the second comment, I changed the np.append... with m = np.insert(m, 1, 0, axis=0) and it works well in both direction (change axis = 1 or 0). I have also changed the lines which gets the number of rows and columns of the array with `nbcol = matrix.shape[1]-1
nbrow = matrix.shape[0]-1`